# Set Fixed Row Height in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have images that I want to render in a GridView. These images are all the same size (250x250). However, I want to display them in 100x100 squares in the GridView.

```
<GridView 
        android:id="@+id/sectionListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
        android:columnWidth="100dp" 
        android:stretchMode="none" 
        >

    </GridView >
```

The above is the grid view. Where I am setting the columnWidth to 100. This actually works but for some reason, the height is always 120, leaving horizontal black bars at the top and bottom of my 250px image. Somehow there are getting 10 pixels on the top and bottom. Changing the vertical and horizontal spacing doesn't help because that affects the spacing between the elements. These black bars on top and bottom are inside the gridView item.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the ImageView which I assume you would be using in your adapter to show the images. You should set android:layout_width and android:layout_height to 100dp and make sure that android:scaleType is set to centerCrop.

Answer (score 0):

In the CustomAdapter

```
view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, rowHigh));
```

rowHigh is the dimension you must to change

Comment: what is `v` in this expample?

Comment: I would assume it stands for view

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gridview, then I think you are also using another item_layout for displaying each item, I'm guessing it is an ImageView as you are trying to display images. Hence you can limit the size of the items to 100 x 100 in that item layout(ie, `android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"`in the item_layout.) Hope it helps.

Comment: I set `android:layout_width` and `_height` and it does not help.